# Editing personal dictionary on Android 6

Tags: file-system, languages, 6.0-marshmallow, dictionary

As it seems Android blocks third party apps from editing the personal dictionaries for some reason.

I just upgraded from Android 4 to 6 and want to import my personal dicitonary, but the apps I've previously used successfully fail (they claim the import was successful, but nothing is imported to my personal dictionary).

Where can I find the file on the phone, where the personal dictionary is saved?
So I can manually copy my old entries to the new system.

Comment: Umm, maybe check this location   /data/data/com.android.providers.userdictionary/databases/user_dict.db

Comment: that seems to be the file, unfortunately it's an sqlite database, not like I expected a plain text file..

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess just replace your IME apk with an older version and then try restoring the database, finally replace the apk again with the new version.